# Bigtable CheckAndMutateRow always returns False

Tags: python, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to use filters to set cells in Bigtable conditionally, however I'm not able to get even the simplest of examples to behave as I expect.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
row = table.row(key, filter_=PassAllFilter(True))
row.set_cell("cf1", "column", "value")
result = row.commit()
print "Result:", result
```

The result I get back is always `False` - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running against the live service or the bigtable emulator?

Comment: Against the live service - I didn't actually know there was an emulator!

Comment: Ha, ok. We occasionally see differing behavior between the two so I thought I'd make sure (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator). Does "key" exist in the table? If so I would think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about the Python client. As noted by Gary your code seems correct. However if no mutations are made you could get back a False value/empty result. The implementation of this logic is open source:

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigtable/row.html#ConditionalRow.commit

If you are still having an issue with this behavior you should feel free to open a GitHub issue here: 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/new/choose